# Error: package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist

Tags: java, android

I've added *commons-codec-1.4.jar* in my project file and also added

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

But whenever I build it it gives me an error:package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist 
Why it's not working?

Comment: "I've added commons-codec-1.4.jar in my project file" -- please explain what you did. "Why it's not working?" -- what you did to add that JAR did not work, apparently. If you are using Android Studio, you should not be using the JAR, but instead use the artifact from a repository. If you are using Eclipse, just putting the JAR in `libs/` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 19):

i were also facing the same issue.
it was resolved by adding `commons-codec.jar`

you may download it from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.7